# How to change the spacing between the headline of bibliography and the first bib entry?

Tags: spacing, biblatex

I use the `\printbibliography` command to generate the section of bibliography for my thesis. The spacing between the headline (e.g. Bibliography) and the first reference (e.g. [1] P. Alfeld, "XXX") seems not to easy to customize. The default spacing is not consistent with other parts (e.g. Abstract and Chapter) of my thesis.

Is there a way to modify this spacing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spacing between the headline and the first reference depends on the bibliography style and may be not consistent with other sectioning commands in the document.

A quick way to modify it is to add some spacing to the hook executed at the beginning of the list of references. This hook is controlled by the command `\AtBeginBibliography`, so adding something like

```
\AtBeginBibliography{\vspace*{10pt}}
```

in the preamble should do what you want.

Adjust `10pt` to fit to your document class settings (use a negative value if you want to reduce the spacing).

In the example below I've exaggerated with `90pt` just to show that it works.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\AtBeginBibliography{\vspace*{90pt}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: It appears that this _adds to_ the spacing, and does not _change_ the spacing.