# Aligning Issue with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, vertical-alignment

I am having an aligning issue with the Biblatex package. The first item of the article list should align with the text "Research Article", but I can not do it in any way. Please note that the texts on both sides align perfectly if I put normal texts instead of printing a bibliography.

[image]

The code of the tex file is below:

**Colors**

```
\newcommand{\primarycolor}{000080}
\newcommand{\secondarycolor}{CCDBD8}
\newcommand{\titlecolor}{464646}
\newcommand{\bodycolor}{080808}
```

**\cvTextColor**

```
\newcommand{\cvTextColor}[2]{\textcolor[HTML]{#1}{#2}}
```

**\cvbar**

```
\newcommand{\cvbar}{
\vspace{1pt}
  \noindent
  \cvTextColor{\primarycolor}{\rule{0.35\textwidth}{3pt}}\hspace{0.01\textwidth}
  \cvTextColor{\secondarycolor}{\rule{0.63\textwidth}{3pt}}
  \vspace{10pt}
}
```

**\cventry**

```
\newcommand{\cventry}[2]{
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{0.24\linewidth} X @{}}
    \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\textbf{\cvTextColor{\titlecolor}{#1}}} & \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\cvTextColor{\bodycolor}{#2}} \\
  \end{tabularx}
}
```

**Main Tex File**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=nejm, sorting=ydnt, defernumbers=true,]{
    biblatex
}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{publication.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}

    \section{Publication}

    \cvbar

    \cventry{Research Article}{ \printbibliography[type=article,heading=none] }
\end{document}
```

**publication.bib**

```
@article{zeng_tariff-based_2023,
    title = {Tariff-{Based} {Optimal} {Scheduling} {Strategy} of {Photovoltaic}-{Storage} for {Industrial} and {Commercial} {Customers}},
    volume = {16},
    doi = {10.3390/en16207079},
    language = {en},
    number = {20},
    urldate = {2023-12-16},
    journal = {Energies},
    author = {Zeng, Zhiyuan and Li, Tianyou and Su, Jun and Sun, Longyi},
    month = oct,
    year = {2023},
    pages = {7079},
}

@article{hedhoud_improvement_2023,
    title = {An improvement of the {CNN}-{XGboost} model for pneumonia disease classification},
    volume = {88},
    doi = {10.5114/pjr.2023.132533},
    number = {1},
    urldate = {2023-12-16},
    journal = {Polish Journal of Radiology},
    author = {Hedhoud, Yousra and Mekhaznia, Tahar and Amroune, Mohamed},
    year = {2023},
    pages = {483--493},
}

@article{nazari_two-stage_2019,
    title = {A two-stage stochastic model for energy storage planning in a microgrid incorporating bilateral contracts and demand response program},
    volume = {21},
    doi = {10.1016/j.est.2018.12.002},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2023-12-16},
    journal = {Journal of Energy Storage},
    author = {Nazari, AmirAli and Keypour, Reza},
    month = feb,
    year = {2019},
    pages = {281--294},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please modify your example to make it compilable. I got the error `Undefined control sequence` on `\cvTextColor`. Please also add an example of your `.bib` file.

Comment: Added the missing codes and the bib file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty hack with `\AtBeginBibliography{\vspace*{-20pt}}`, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148460/how-to-change-the-spacing-between-the-headline-of-bibliography-and-the-first-bib).

```
\begin{filecontents}{publication.bib}
@article{zeng_tariff-based_2023,
    title = {Tariff-{Based} {Optimal} {Scheduling} {Strategy} of {Photovoltaic}-{Storage} for {Industrial} and {Commercial} {Customers}},
    volume = {16},
    doi = {10.3390/en16207079},
    language = {en},
    number = {20},
    urldate = {2023-12-16},
    journal = {Energies},
    author = {Zeng, Zhiyuan and Li, Tianyou and Su, Jun and Sun, Longyi},
    month = oct,
    year = {2023},
    pages = {7079},
}

@article{hedhoud_improvement_2023,
    title = {An improvement of the {CNN}-{XGboost} model for pneumonia disease classification},
    volume = {88},
    doi = {10.5114/pjr.2023.132533},
    number = {1},
    urldate = {2023-12-16},
    journal = {Polish Journal of Radiology},
    author = {Hedhoud, Yousra and Mekhaznia, Tahar and Amroune, Mohamed},
    year = {2023},
    pages = {483--493},
}

@article{nazari_two-stage_2019,
    title = {A two-stage stochastic model for energy storage planning in a microgrid incorporating bilateral contracts and demand response program},
    volume = {21},
    doi = {10.1016/j.est.2018.12.002},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2023-12-16},
    journal = {Journal of Energy Storage},
    author = {Nazari, AmirAli and Keypour, Reza},
    month = feb,
    year = {2019},
    pages = {281--294},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\newcommand{\primarycolor}{000080}
\newcommand{\secondarycolor}{CCDBD8}
\newcommand{\titlecolor}{464646}
\newcommand{\bodycolor}{080808}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=nejm, sorting=ydnt, defernumbers=true,]{
    biblatex
}
\newcommand{\cvTextColor}[2]{\textcolor[HTML]{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\cvbar}{
\vspace{1pt}
  \noindent
  \cvTextColor{\primarycolor}{\rule{0.35\textwidth}{3pt}}\hspace{0.01\textwidth}
  \cvTextColor{\secondarycolor}{\rule{0.63\textwidth}{3pt}}
  \vspace{10pt}
}
\AtBeginBibliography{\vspace*{-20pt}}
\newcommand{\cventry}[2]{
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{0.24\linewidth} X @{}}
    \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\textbf{\cvTextColor{\titlecolor}{#1}}} & \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\cvTextColor{\bodycolor}{#2}} \\
  \end{tabularx}
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{publication.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}

    \section{Publication}

    \cvbar

    \cventry{Research Article}{\printbibliography[type=article,heading=none]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It Worked!

Comment: @lily_scarlett23 Maybe there is a more elegant way but I didn't know it. Thank you for accepting my answer.